# How do I move a content control in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

This may be a stupid question, but I don't find any option, so maybe someone here can enlighten me.

I have an empty Word document where I've added a picture content control. However, I want to move the content control from the right side to the left side. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the picture content control, click 'Size and Position', click on the text wrapping tab, click square.

Now you can move it anywhere just like a normal picture:

[image]
[image]